# How to install Protobuf and curve25519 extensions in php (windows)?

Tags: php, api, wamp

I am trying to run an API in wamp2.5 on Windows8 which requires php extensions Protobuf and curve2551. My problem is I found information on adding these extensions on MAC/linux but not windows.
Would appreciate help on how I could accomplish this or a friendly point in the direction where I could get some relevant information.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you might get `protocolbuffers` [from here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/protocolbuffers/) compiled for windows. Make sure you download the Thread Safe (TS) version compatible with your PHP version.

Comment: And this may help you with Curve [a github repo](https://github.com/lt/PHP-Curve25519) No guarantees

Comment: No luck. None of those options worked